Why did the Federation ban DNA resequencing?
It makes no sense that the entire Federation and group of many planets would ban DNA reseqeuncing just because of a horrific  experience the humans had with it. Other members of the Federation may have had a bad experience with it. But still it makes no sense.

"a bad experience" seems like an understatement.

KHHHHAAAANNNNNAN!!!

Presumably other races had also had issues with their own augmented citizens. When you enhance a Bolian, do you also enhance their ambition?

Kahn was generally regarded as a benevolent dictator, just had a bad rap later on.

@JiminyCricket. - "Like many genocidal warlords bent on world domination, Khan was largely misunderstood during his own lifetime"

"It makes no sense" to some people. You can see a lot of overreaction to events similar to that in our society if you are willing to take a step back to get a bit of perspective. And sometimes an overreaction is the correct response.

@cybernetic.nomad If it was in fact the correct response, it would not have been an overreaction.  Just a reaction.

It's a response to a deeply traumatic event that killed tens of millions. The initial fear apparently hardened into dogma around the time that humanity became a founding member of the Federation; one may speculate that humanity made this prohibition a foundational principle of the new organization (and this may have been okay with other species who wanted no part of humanity's violence and things that had provoked it). For a historical comparison, American eugenics laws became very unpopular after WWII.
For another real world example of long-lasting impacts of traumatic events, consider the sack of Rome by the Celts in 390 BC. This caused a dread of Celts for centuries:

Despite Rome defeating the Senones in the Battle of Sentinum (295)
during the Third Samnite War (298-290), popular fear of Gauls
persisted. In 228, 216, and 114 fears of Gallic attacks led to the
Romans performing human sacrifices by burying alive a pair of Gauls
and a pair of Greeks even though human sacrifice was not a Roman
custom.


I think this answer is correct to refer to American experience with eugenics laws.  Star Trek was conceived when many of its viewers were either participants in WW2, or were their children and grandchildren.  Lessons and fears from that awful conflict were were fresh in everyone's minds, along with other social issues of the day, and Star Trek was not afraid to comment on such things.

@WayneConrad in my head canon the Eugenics wars were a last gasp of WWII era scientists trying to get Eugenics right for peace and failing epically.  Which is why it makes zero sense to keep retconning the dates.  Also out-universe the obsession with Khan didn't happen until well after STII.  Note second season TNG "Unnatural Selection" which is impossible to reconcile with the rest of Trek no one vetoed at the time in 1989.
